# How to send get requests from apache log file to web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache, mono, stress-testing

ASP.NET MVC4 web application (shopping cart) is running with mono, apache and mod_mono in Debian.
Sometimes it stops responging or is slow.

Apache acces log file contains parts which may be can used to reproduce the issue:

```
1.4.24.123 - - [25/Nov/2014:19:50:06 +0200] "GET /store/StoreImage/Thumb?product=350-00315&size=198 HTTP/1.1" 200 5231 "http://www.example.com/store/Store/Details?product=350-00315" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"

1.4.24.123 - - [25/Nov/2014:19:50:06 +0200] "GET /store/Image/Icon HTTP/1.1" 200 2721 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"

1.4.24.123 - - [25/Nov/2014:19:50:06 +0200] "GET /store/Image/Icon HTTP/1.1" 200 2721 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

etc.
How to send those requests to web site for testing the site from windows ? Is there some free tool or converter which reads apache log file and sends those requests ?
Or how to create MVC4 controller which accepts uploaded this file, parsest it and isses web requests from it to site ? Or is there some web page which can do it ?
Or some testing spidder which invokes all urls from all pages in site rapidly ?

Comment: Some strategies here: https://www.igvita.com/2008/09/30/load-testing-with-log-replay/

Comment: Thank you. ab reads only main page. Page contains lot of images. Where to find tool which mimics browser more closely, e.q reads all image links in page also ?